# jQuery each-loop access every index text element

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, each

I have the below snippet.

If you run the snippet you are able to see that the output is correct but I need to store each span's text element in a variable to process further.  If possible I would prefer a solution without a recursive function.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').click(function (e) {
     
      let fo; let foo; let fooo;
      $(e.currentTarget).children('span').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
        // Expected Output
        // fo = li1(2)   +span1
        // foo = li1(2)  +span2
        // fooo = li1(2) +span3
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span style="display: block;">li1 + span1</span>
      <span style="display: block;">li1 + span2</span>
      <span style="display: block;">li1 + span3</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span style="display: block;">li2 + span1</span>
      <span style="display: block;">li2 + span2</span>
      <span style="display: block;">li3 + span3</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not use the jQuery each loop, as it is very slow. If you want to use a loop you should use a native JavaScript loop, which is about ten times faster.

Comment: Thank you, that is interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you require you could build an array of all the `span` texts by using `map()`. This method has the advantage of being dynamic enough to work for any number of child elements.

Once you've built the array you can either loop over it to work with all values, or select a specific instance by its index. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').click(function(e) {
    var textValues = $(this).children('span').map(function() {
      return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    
    console.log(textValues[1]); // the second item
    console.log(textValues); // all
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span style="display: block;">li1 + span1</span>
      <span style="display: block;">li1 + span2</span>
      <span style="display: block;">li1 + span3</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span style="display: block;">li2 + span1</span>
      <span style="display: block;">li2 + span2</span>
      <span style="display: block;">li3 + span3</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the working snippet. Unfortunately, I receive "undefined" in my live implementation. Do you have any idea why this could be?
In my approach I get the first and the last value with workarounds:
        fo = $(e.target).siblings('span:first').text();
        foo = $(e.target).children().remove().end().text();

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really diagnose an issue without seeing it. It may be worth updating your question with a more accurate version of your HTML output. As a guess, you could try `find()` instead of `children()`, as the latter relies on the `span` being a child of the `li`, whereas `find()` will search any level of descendant.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have 3 variables, then why not simply take `nth-child` 3 times using [eq selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').click(function (e) {
     
      let fo = $(this).find("span:eq(0)").html(); 
      let foo = $(this).find("span:eq(1)").html();
      let fooo = $(this).find("span:eq(2)").html();
      console.log(fo, foo, fooo);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span style="display: block;">li1 + span1</span>
      <span style="display: block;">li1 + span2</span>
      <span style="display: block;">li1 + span3</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span style="display: block;">li2 + span1</span>
      <span style="display: block;">li2 + span2</span>
      <span style="display: block;">li3 + span3</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the working snippet. Unfortunately, I receive "undefined" in my live implementation. Do you have any idea why this could be? In my approach I get the first and the last value with workarounds: fo = $(e.target).siblings('span:first').text(); foo = $(e.target).children().remove().end().text();